# Transparent JPanel, Canvas background in JFrame

Tags: java

I wanna make canvas background and add some elements on top of it. For this goal I made JPanel as transparent container with setOpaque(false) and added it as first of JFrame container, then I added canvas with black background (in future I wanna set animation) to JFrame as second element.

But I can't undestand why i see grey background, not a black.
Any suggestions?

```java
public class Game extends JFrame {
    public Container container; //Game container with components
    public Canvas backgroundLayer; //Background layer of a game
    public JPanel elementsLayer; //elements panel (top of backgroundLayer), holds different elements

    private Dimension startGameDimension = new Dimension(800,600); //start game dimension

    public Game() {
        //init main window
        super("Astra LaserForces");
        setSize(startGameDimension);
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        container=getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //init jpanel elements layer
        elementsLayer=new JPanel();
        elementsLayer.setSize(startGameDimension);
        elementsLayer.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        elementsLayer.setOpaque(false);
        container.add(elementsLayer);

        //init canvas background layer
        backgroundLayer = new Canvas();
        backgroundLayer.setSize(startGameDimension);
        backgroundLayer.setBackground(Color.BLACK); //set default black color
        container.add(backgroundLayer);

    }

    //start game
    public void start() {
        setVisible(true);

    }

    //create new instance of game and start it
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game().start();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of that JPanel?

Comment: Main aim to create animated background thats you can change in future and jpanel as top container for top elements. For example i have background animation with stars and menu with buttons. When i click start game, my canvas will change animation and my jpanel destroy menu component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Container.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) doesn't stack components on top of each other -- it `appends` them according to the installed `LayoutManager`. Have a look at `JLayeredPane` instead to achieve the effect you're looking for.

But also consider just drawing everything in the `Canvas` directly (first the background, then the foreground) to avoid the whole Swing kitchen sink.